# Populate a dropdownbox using Jquery and AJAX requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, append

I get the data from Jquery AJAX callback function, i have a

> < select class="multi" id="abc" name="xyz">

I do the append on id like this

```
$("#abc").append("<option value=\"" + data.externals[j].ITEM_NAME + "\">"+ data.externals[j].ITEM_NAME + "</option>")
```

The problem I am suffering is in our request we also have multiple dropdown with the same id for each dropdown as we do all this in .js file. The dropdown value is coming for only one list. It is not coming for others dropdown as i am using ID to append data. and offcourse I cant even use the class name because there are other function in there which required the id of that dropdown exactly the same. Is there any solution to this ?

Comment: ID's should be UNIQUE!

Comment: It doesn't follow from your statement why exactly you couldn't use a class name to distinguish the dropdowns.  Those are independent of the ids.  But you should still have unique ids.